# Auth::attempt is not checking for the username and password

Tags: php, laravel-4

routes.php

```
//form login
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'guest', function()
{
    return View::make('login');
}));

// check login
Route::post('login', 'HomeController@validate');
```

HomeController.php

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish to use controllers instead of, or in addition to, Closure
    | based routes. That's great! Here is an example controller method to
    | get you started. To route to this controller, just add the route:
    |
    |   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
    |
    */

    public function validate() 
    {
        // set the remember me cookie if the user check the box
        $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;
        // attempt to do the login

        $email = Input::get('username');
        $pass = Input::get('password');
        $password = Hash::check($remember,$pass);
        $credentials = array(
        'username' => "'$email'",
        'password' => "'$pass'"
        );
        $auth=Auth::attempt(array(
      'username' => "'$email'",
        'password' => "'$pass'",
));
        if($auth) {
             return 'success';
        }
        else {
             return 'auth failed';
        } 

    }

}
```

User.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

}
```

login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Simple Login</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php echo Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'role' => 'form')) ?>
        <h2>Please sign in</h2>
        <!-- if there are login errors, show them here -->
        <p>
            <?php  if(Session::has('flash_notice')): ?>
                <div id="flash_notice"><?php echo Session::get('flash_notice') ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo Input::old('username') ?>" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" />
        <input name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" type="password" />
        <div>
            <input name="remember" type="checkbox" /> Remember me
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
    <?php echo Form::close() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using laravel4 on my xamppp machine . I have made a simple login form in which a registered user can login in , to see the dashboard but When i use **Auth::attempt**   to check the user is valid or not It will always shows me an error 'the username of password is wrong '

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(3, 'Imron Rosdiana', 'imron02', 'imron@rosdiana.com', '$2y$10$bAwhqg41gHPOLD36aVxQi.ItviwlN663gCIt6S8H2VjeR8kZWHAZy', 'pvusxXobB9wAWKReXte5pv51vD4BKfPi4LjEV9JUlArLdmc4DL30eipAJ6Nb', '2014-04-22 16:45:57', '2014-04-28 03:45:26');
```

USERNAME:imron02
PASSWORD:123456 (by using hash::make i have inserted the password)

I know so many users have asked this question but still i am getting stuck at the same and everytime i get **auth failed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part:

```
$credentials = array(
        'username' => "'$email'",
        'password' => "'$pass'"
        );
$auth=Auth::attempt(array(
      'username' => "'$email'",
        'password' => "'$pass'",
));
```

To this:

```
$credentials = array(
        'username' => $email,
        'password' => $pass
        );
$auth=Auth::attempt($credentials);
```

Refer to [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users).

But while doing this make sure you have a column corresponding to username in your table. I had to mention this because the username you provided does not seem to be an email id. The username and password combination should exist in the corresponding table in order to authenticate.

If you are planning to take email id as the username you need to change this line:

```
'username' => $email,
```

to this:

```
'email' => $email,
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Remove the quotes from variable. $email and $pass

```
    $auth=Auth::attempt(array
      (
        'username' => $email,
        'password' => $pass,
      )
```